# How to set the position of the text cursor inside a form field

Tags: html, css, cursor-position

When I click on the text box, I want the cursor to appear at the top left, and advance as you would advance down a word doc. Instead, it starts in the middle and pressing enter submits the string.

What I'm looking to do also is make it so pressing enter line breaks, rather than submits, and the cursor start at the top left of the page rather than the middle left.

```
<head>
<title>Notepad</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/styles.css">
<script type= "text/javascript" src="../javascripts/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="form2" value autofocus="on">
</form>
</body>
```

current form so far.

Comment: Use `<textarea>` tag instead of `<input>`.

Comment: `<textarea type="text" id="form2" value autofocus="on">`
would work?
would i then set textarea in the css file?

Comment: This is very basic HTML - you'll find everything you need to know in Google and in any basic HTML tutorial. In case you'll face specific problem post it here.

Comment: sorry, i searched around for stuff to do with the <input> tag, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input type=text>`.